# angular.js: How to put data from JSON to template and the result into main website?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm using `angular.js` and the directive `angucomplete-alt` to let the user search and select an article. With this selection the content will be taken from the DB via http-post-request. But now I don't know how to put the result into the main-container.

So I have to take the template.html and connect the response to the template and put everything into `<main>`. How do I have to do that?

**HTML:**

```
<main id="target">
    <div>Any content</div>
    <div id="searching" ng-controller='search'>
        <div angucomplete-alt id="s1" selected-object="select" remote-url="search.php?q=" remote-url-data-field="results" title-field="title" description-field="description"></div>
    </div>
</main>
```

**angular.js:**

```
app.controller('search', ['$scope', '$http',
    function s1($scope, $http) {

        $scope.select = function(selected) {
            if (selected) {
                /* Now get the info */
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: "script.php",
                    data: { title: selected.title },
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
                })
                .success(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    /* put the response connected with template.html into main-container */
                });
            }
        };

    }
]);
```

**UPDATE:**

Maybe I'm thinking wrong... but this is my concept:

At the beginning in the main-container there is the search-box. If the user is searching an article, the result of the request gives me a json-array.

The content of this array should be merged within a template-file, which could look like this:

**template.html**

```
<div>{{name}}</div>
<section>{{content}}</section>
```

... and so on. So the JSON-result is now in the template-file. This complete result should be put into the main-container - which means the search-box is being replaced.

The result would be:

**Result:**

```
<main id="target">
    <div>Layla</div>
    <section>Layla is a beautiful girl.</section>
</main>
```

Comment: Provide a link to jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like that :

**JS**
Add an array var in your controller : `var $scope.myNeeds= [];`

Then fill it with your request

```
.success(function(response) {
    for(var number in response)
        $scope.myNeeds.push(response[number]);
});
```

Then in your **HTML** (don't forget to repeat the div you want with `ng-repeat`)

```
<main id="target" ng-controller="search">
    <div ng-repeat="myNeed in search.myNees">
        <div>{{myNeed.name}}</div>
        <div>{{myNeed.content}}</div>
    </div>
    <div id="searching" ng-controller='search'>
        <div angucomplete-alt id="s1" selected-object="select" remote-url="search.php?q=" remote-url-data-field="results" title-field="title" description-field="description"></div>
    </div>
</main>
```

This code will work if you have a JSON like this :

```
[
    {
        "name":"First part",
        "content":??? /*a string or an array, depends on what you want*/
    },
    {
        "name":"Second Part",
        "surname":??? /*a string or an array, depends on what you want*/
    }
    ...
    ...
]
```

But I let you change the code in your HTML & in your JSON to get what you want !

Comment: Yes, the response is an array. The elements of the array should be used in a template-file. And everything together should be put into main.

Comment: And `main` is outside of the search-scope. So I have to create this scope first, right?

Comment: Yeah you create it in your controller : `var $scope = this;`
And I edited my post to show you how it is with an array

Comment: Maybe I missunderstand you. I have updated the post. Please have a look at it... (This example has no array)

Comment: Okay,edited again ! You have to repeat a div, containing the two divs you want to dynamically fill. For that, you have to call your controller in your main or in a div containing the div where you do your `ng-repeat` .. I hope you have understood, I hardly have understood myself ^^'

Comment: Ok, I see it seems to be impossible. The problem is, that I want to put a completely new content to the main-container. Therefore I want to use a template.html. File. The structure is completely different from the search box. So there could be a table oder multiple images or anything else. Your solution just puts the content of the JSON in an already existing structure. That's not what I need.

Comment: do you want something like that ? (I edited the HTML code only)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77168/discussion-between-user3142695-and-tektiv).